# grabbing the element which as a perticular class attached to it

Tags: jquery

i am trying to hide a list item which has perticular class attached to it.
here is my code

```
var currentImageOnDisplay=$('#thumbsList li').hasClass('currentThumbNail');
```

now if I alert this it shows true.
How come i grab the element index of the LI having this `currentThumbNail` class? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Basically `.hasClass('className')` will return a `Boolean` based on the selected element having that class or not. You should use a `element with class` selector to accomplish your task.

Try,

```
var currentImageOnDisplay = $('#thumbsList li.currentThumbNail')
```

Comment: ok if now i want to do something on a list item that is previous  to that one should i check for it's index and do something on that index -1?

Comment: if you want to grab the previous sibling you can use `.prev()`.? Is that you want.?

Comment: @designerNProgrammer it will be like `$('#thumbsList li.currentThumbNail').prev()`